# Django template: compare two dates, are same month?

Tags: django-templates

I have two dates and I want to see if they have the same month. I was trying:

```
{% if {{event.date_to|date:"m"}} = {{event.date_from|date:"m"}} %}
     <a>same!</a>
{%endif%}
```

I get an error when rendering: Could not parse the remainder. date_to and date_from are both DateTimeField(). At this point, I am thinking of doing the comparison in the view and passing an is_same_date value. However, I though I'd first ask if it could be done in the template.

Comment: Thanks for the offer :) I figured something out, though, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was some silly typo-like things. This worked.

```
{% if event.date_from|date:"m" == event.date_to|date:"m" %}
```

It also works with day and month, etc. "d m"